# Accessing data from a relative kubenetes service url from another service using nodejs in the same cluster

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I am in a kubernetes cluster with two services running. One of the services expose a endpoint like `/customer/servcie-endpoint` and other service is a nodejs application which is trying to access data from this service. Axios doesn't work as it needs a host to work with.

If I do a kubectl exec shell and run `curl /customer/servcie-endpoint` I receive all the data.

I am not sure how to get this data in a nodejs application. Sry for naive ask!

Comment: Some details seem to be missing here. When you say you're doing `kubectl exec`, which pod are you targeting exactly? The nodejs application or the first service you've specified? Either way, it feels very weird that your curl command should work, as it is missing a host. That command should produce the following error - `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`